Azure Databricks: PySpark: Unable to validate XML file using XSD
Here is what I did.

Created an XML file

xmlPath = "dbfs:/mnt/books.xml"
xmlString = """
  <book id="bk103">
    <author>Corets, Eva</author>
    <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
  </book>"""
dbutils.fs.put(xmlPath, xmlString, True)


Created an XSD file

xsd_Path = "dbfs:/mnt/books.xsd"
xsd_String = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="book">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="author" type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:element name="title" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>"""

dbutils.fs.put(xsd_Path, xsd_String,True)


Reading the file with option rowValidationXSDPath

df = (spark.read
    .format("xml")
    .option("rowTag", "book")
    .option("rowValidationXSDPath", xsd_Path)
    .load(xmlPath))
df.printSchema()


Getting error message
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 30.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 30.0 (TID 123) (10.139.64.10 executor driver): java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'file:/local_disk0/spark-*************/dbfs:/mnt/books.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>


Please assist to fix the error.

Did you manage to fix the problem?

You can add the XSD file to the SparkContext using:
spark.sparkContext.addFile("path/to/your/file.xsd")

This makes the file available on all the nodes in the cluster.
More details: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkContext.addFile.html
